How can I change 'no rows to show' to a dynamic component in ag-grid-angular?
I want to create a dynamic component and it should dynamically take title and description and show it instead of the static default text of 'no rows to show'
So for the time being you can directly add template over here
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
...
 overlayNoRowsTemplate: `<div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <img src="assets/images/folder-plus.svg" alt="No data" class="w-10 h-10 text-gray-400">
    <p class="font-bold text-xl text-gray-500 py-3">No data found</p>
      <p class="text-base text-gray-400">Data does not exist for selected filters.</p>
    </div>`,
...
}

But now if you want to add a dynamic component over here with title and description so how to do that ?

For simple text change or small change you can add HTML template like that. But if you want to create a dynamic component then you just have to create an ag grid component like follow
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ILoadingOverlayAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'app-no-row-data',
templateUrl: './no-row-data.component.html',
})

export class NoRowDataComponent implements ILoadingOverlayAngularComp  {
title: string = '';
description: string = '';

 constructor() { }

 agInit(params: any): void {
   this.title = params.title || 'No Rows';
   this.description = params.description || 'No data available.';
 }

}

Now in the table component where you want to add this add the following options in the grid options
components: {
  customNoRowsOverlay: NoRowDataComponent,
},
// If you want to have dynamic message for different grids, just pass input from the table component and append that dynamic message over here in title and description.
noRowsOverlayComponent: 'customNoRowsOverlay',
noRowsOverlayComponentParams: {
  title: this.i18NextService.t('reports.emptyReportTableTitle') as string,
  description: this.i18NextService.t(
    'reports.emptReportTableDescription'
  ) as string,
},

